# Should CORS headers be added to my server OR the CDN?

Tags: nginx, cors, amazon-cloudfront

On my site: `www.my-site.com`, I've CDN configured to deliver the image assets from url: `data.my-site.com`. Now, I'm looking to setup CORS for the images; so that I can have `crossorigin="anonymous"` defined in the image tags.

I'm however confused whether I should have CORS headers setup on my server (NGINX) OR the CDN?

Because the requests are being originated from my server to the CDN. Can someone help?

Comment: "Because the requests are being originated from my server to the CDN."  Can you elaborate on this?  If you're making server-side requests, there's no need for CORS at all.  But, that doesn't sound at all like what you're doing.  Sounds to me like you basically have two origins, `www.my-site.com` and `data.my-site.com`, both of which are being accessed client-side.

Comment: No, my mistake. Requests are being made directly by the clients to the CDN. Yes, I have `www.my-site.com` where all the views/html resides; and the static assets are being loaded from `data.my-site.com`.